# What do the numbers mean in Canon printer profile names?

Tags: canon, printing, color-management

When selecting a Profile in Lightroom's Print Module > Print Job panel, I'm a little confused. I have some Canon Matte Photo Paper, and there is only a single profile that it could be, but I also have a sample pack of Canon Pro Platinum Photo Paper.

Looking at the available profiles, there are two possibilities:

- `Canon Pro 100s <PT> 1/2 Photo Paper Pro Platinum`
- `Canon Pro 100s <PT> 3 Photo Paper Pro Platinum`

What does the number (e.g. "1/2" or "3") between **`<PT>`** and Photo **Paper Pro Platinum** mean?

Comment: I am interested as well as i have the Canon Pro-10 and i do see the <LU>, <MP>, <SG> on some of my color options.

Comment: @thebtm The letters in the angle brackets are the type of paper, for example <LU> is lustre, <PT> is platinum. I'm interested in the numbers that follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hope this helps - Asked my Canon Rep as I was also interested and this is what he sent me;*

The ICC profiles installed for your printer and Canon photo paper appear as follows.

CANON - **PRINTER MODEL**    < **PAPER TYPE**>    **PRINT QUALITY**

(For example: **Canon Pro9000 PR1)**

**(1) Printer model name**

**(2) Media type**

Each letter pair represents its respective Media type.

**PR** = Canon Photo Paper Pro and Pro II

**SP:** = Canon Photo Paper Plus Glossy

**MP:** = Canon Matte Photo Paper

**SG:** = Canon Photo Paper Plus Semi-gloss

**GL:** = Canon Photo Paper Plus Glossy II

**PT:** = Canon Photo Paper Pro Platinum

**(3) Print quality**

The numbers correspond to the numbers on the print quality slide bar in the [Custom Quality] dialog box opened from the [Main] tab of the printer driver. The lower the number, the finer the quality.

Comment: That makes me mad at Canon. All this time, I could have been getting better quality in my prints, except they didn't document how to use it effectively.